# Newly built PC: no video output after first shutoff

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, uefi, computer-building

I am building a mini-itx desktop for daily use. Here are the specs:

- motherboard: ASRock Z390M-ITX/ac
- cpu: Intel i5 9600KF
- gpu: MSI GTX750Ti TwinFrozR
- ram: G.SKILL Ripjaws 2x8GB 3200MHz
- storage: ADATA 512GB m2 drive
- psu: CoolerMaster ATX 600W

I successfully assembled the machine and booted it up. The motherboard's UEFI greeted me with a "Please insert boot medium"  message. Because I had not mounted the motherboard inside the case at that point and since the board itself does not have a power button, I decided to shut it off using the PSU switch. I plugged in my boot usb stick and keyboard and powered it on by shorting the power button pins on the motherboard. The fans on the cpu, the gpu and the psu are running but I'm not getting any video output whatsoever. I do not know which component is at fault.

So far I have managed to exclude both the graphics card and the PSU by plugging in spare ones (GTX 950Ti, XFX 550W) that are 100% functional. I have also tried multiple displays, output ports and cables just to make sure it's not the case.
I also tried resetting the motherboards CMOS memory. The manual instructs you to switch off the PSU and then shorting two pins for 10 seconds. This did not resolve the issue either.

Is it possible that I have damaged the motherboard by hitting the psu switch? Perhaps it's just UEFI-related and caused by plugging in multiple USB devices and I'm just not able to correctly reset the mobo's memory?

Comment: Also try re-seating the RAM. Since you have 2 sticks, try with just one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've tried that already - swapped the sticks and tried with one at a time.

Comment: *"Is it possible that I have damaged the motherboard by hitting the PSU switch?"* - If you have tested all the other components, it seems probable that either the motherboard or possibly the CPU was affected. And it is certainly possible (100%, without a doubt) to kill a motherboard while attempting to operate it outside its case.